# How to render adobe after effect from script?

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I need to render a composition with script. In project panel there're 7 composition. the index of composition to render is 3. inside composition there're 5 items. And version adobe after effect i'm using is After Effect CS6. I try so many things with the documentation. But, I don't how to exactly to select item to pass to render. Because of that. its not automatically to render.

> You must have at least one render item quequed in order to render

```
app.project.renderQueue.render();
```

To make simple what i try. i just discard anything that don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I did not test it but aggregated it from some old scripts of mine. Try it this way.

```
var comp = app.project.item(3);
// var testComp = app.project.items.addComp("testComp", 100, 100, 1, 1, 25);
app.project.renderQueue.items.add(comp);
app.project.renderQueue.render();
```

**Edit:** For your further questions about the output module you should take a look at the docs @stib suggested and you can also take a look at some scripts of mine https://github.com/fabianmoronzirfas/render-tools

Comment: its works, but, the render format in avi and no sound. I want it render to mp4 and have sound.

Comment: Have a look at the docs for the outputModule object. http://docs.aenhancers.com/renderqueue/outputmodule/ You need to set up an output module for the item or it will use default settings